# Counting foreground objects in a binary image

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have an image sequence (video). I would like to count the number of objects in the image sequence. But the main objective is to count them once, meaning not just in each and every frame, since an object may exist in for several frames. My idea is to count the objects as they exit the screen, because of less occlusions. I am thinking of doing this by scanning the bottom part of the image for non zero pixels.

I have a CV_FILLED binary image (from rectangle function) where I want to do the scanning, then create an instance on an object if abject is found. But this scanning will not be scanning each and every pixel along the horizontal line, just certain sections.

Like we could do it over ranges, say certain columns, then skip by a margin.

A sample binary image I have is attached [image: CV_FILLED binary image]. This is an image obtained from the feed. I do not want to count only the objects in this image, but also those that are still coming.

A full picture of detected objects is attached here.Your guidance or constructive criticism is welcome 
* I do not want to use CVBlob

Comment: *Note - CVBlobLib is not allowed : And what woudl be the reason for that? Homework ? It is generally a good idea to reuse other people's work; especially if they do what you want to achieve

Comment: But what I'm interested in more is how to relate blobs from frame i to frame i+1? So that we don't have to detect the same frame more than once...

Comment: And? You can use cvBlobLib to detect blobs frame after frame. What is important is what you do with it afterwards .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx guys. I managed to solve this already. I used small ROIs along the paths of the squares, and found `countNonZero()` within the ROI.

I kept on checking with `boolean` variables to see if the ROI still had the white pixels. If not, incremented counter. Worked well, and I was able to count.

Thx for your input...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use cvBlobLib, you could use the contour detection that is part of OpenCV.

There is a tutorial [on the website.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

The doc for the method is [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours). Your image seem pretty simple, but if you get blobs with occlusions and so you want to look at the CV_RETR_EXTERNAL constant to get only the outer contours.

That is what I usualy use, even though it needs a bit more work to use the results of the method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the squares do not overlap at the bottom, I suggest the following:

scan the very bottom row of the image and identify those connected pixels which are white. Each white line will correspond to one square. Save the center of the white line segment and its length. In the next frame, do the same and associate the corresponding line segments to the previous (same length and center very close). When you cannot find a corresponding line segment anymore, the square has moved out of the image which means you can increase your squares counter by one. Note that line segments at the right and left ends of the line will have decreasing length with every frame.